# How to transform text into list of words grouped by count using Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, collections

I have String text like that:

```
val text: String = "aa bb cc aa bb aa aa / <"
```

I am try first to skip special characters like `<*/&^$` , then group words into list of object word like that:

```
data class Word(val id: Int, val text: String, val count: Int)

listOf(Word(1, aa, 4), Word(2, bb, 2), Word(3, cc, 1))
```

This is my approach but it requires 3 loops which is bad plus the boiler plate code

```
 val wordWithCountMap = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
 text.trim().split(" ").forEach { word ->
        if (word.isNotEmpty() && word.isNotBlank()) {
            val key = regex.replace(word, "")
            wordWithCountMap[key] = wordWithCountMap[word]?.plus(1) ?: 1
        }
    }

 val wordList = arrayListOf<Word>()
 wordWithCountMap.onEachIndexed { index, entry ->
      wordList.add(
         Word(
                id = index, text = entry.key,
                count = entry.value
         )
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val text: String = "aa bb cc aa bb aa aa / <"

data class Word(
  val id: Int,
  val text: String,
  val count: Int
)

val result = text
  .split("\\b".toRegex())
  .filter { it.any { char -> char.isLetterOrDigit() } }
  .groupingBy { it }
  .eachCount()
  .entries
  .sortedByDescending { it.value }   // mabye remove this line (see @mattFreake's comment below)
  .mapIndexed { index, textCount -> Word(index + 1, textCount.key, textCount.value) }

result.forEach(::println)
```

Comment: Perfect, 
How many loops in this solution?

Comment: Tiny tweak: the `.map{ it }` could be `.entries`.

Comment: One thing. This orders by the number of occurrences (rather than the original order in the String). Possibly that's not a problem, or is what the OP wanted anyway.

Comment: You are of course right. It depends on the OP's intent, it is not clear with the given input string.

Comment: No problem, I am not interested in sorting, but it is ok, maybe somebody else need it.